# StackNavigator Back Swipe Callback

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is there a way to invoke a function when the back swipe gesture is performed?

My view has a custom back button on the top left corner of the navbar. When that button is pressed, I clean up code, then the view is popped. I'm looking to perform this same clean up code when the StackNavigator's back gesture is performed on this particular view. Is this possible using the default back swipe gesture?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the [navigation listeners](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle), on the particular screen where you want to perform the operation.

The transitions can be listened by

```
const didBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
  'didBlur',
  payload => {
    console.debug('didBlur', payload);
  }
);
```

The `JSON object` for the `payload` will look like this

```
{
  action: { type: 'Navigation/COMPLETE_TRANSITION', key: 'StackRouterRoot' },
  context: 'id-1518521010538-2:Navigation/COMPLETE_TRANSITION_Root',
  lastState: undefined,
  state: undefined,
  type: 'didBlur',
};
```

therefore you can add a conditional based on the `lastState`

Also dont forget to remove the listener

```
didBlurSubscription.remove();
```

Comment: I've started to implement this and have gotten it to fire only when I do not remove the subscription. Besides the issues that may cause, I cannot differentiate between back blurs and forward blurs. It seems the only way I can check is to set a variable stating when I'm doing a forward transition and when it is not set, assume it's the back transition. Is there a better way to differentiate between back and forward transitions?

Comment: I haven't completely utilized this yet, but I think `state` and `lastState` comparison should get you a solution if it is forward or back transition.

Comment: Unfortunately those two fields are always left undefined when they are sent. If i did get those values, this solution would work easily. As of now,  I moved the cleanup function to the previous view and implement the `willFocus` event

Comment: It doesn't even fire for me on swipe back. Only when i exit using 'navigate'. Can't believer there is no way to handle this...